# react-native-image-picker not returning data from camera

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm using [react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker) to load photos. This seems to work well for photos pulled out of the camera roll, but if the user chooses to take a photo, there's no data in the response, just an empty string.

I'm using these options:

```
{
  title: 'Upload Photo',
  cancelButtonTitle: 'Cancel',
  takePhotoButtonTitle: 'Take Photo...',
  chooseFromLibraryButtonTitle: 'Choose from Library...',
  noData: false,
  mediaType: 'photo',
  quality: 0.2,
}
```

and launching the image picker with:

```
UIImagePickerManager.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

will work fine for images picked out of the camera roll, but will give me an empty string for `response.data` when an new image is taken with the camera.

What gives?

Comment: Are you on iOS or Android?

Comment: So far, just on iOS. But I'd like a solution that works on both.

Comment: It works fine for me on iOS .. I've got a problem with Android.

Comment: The problem is not as you describe. In android it does get the data and is saved temporarily  to sd card.  Here the actual problem is react native <image> is not able to load image from sdcard.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878809/react-native-image-not-loading-image-from-sdcard-in-android?noredirect=1#comment63901416_37878809

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show image using data (noData:false)
use this:

```
UIImagePickerManager.showImagePicker(options, response => {
    if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
    } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
    } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
    } else {
        const source = {uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data};
        this.setState({
            avatarSource: source,
        });
    }
});
```

and set avatarSource state for image source