# React Native <Image> not loading image from sdcard in android

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to load image from external sdcard after I take photo from camera in React native image component as following, but it is not rendering  in android. I even checked if there is image missing at that location, but that's not the problem.  But it works well in case of iOS to load image from location after taking photo from camera.

```
 <Image source={{uri:'/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/image-0ea0d714-9469-432b-8869-b6637be2be10.jpg'}} style={{height:200, width:200}} />
```

Here's my permission list in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<!-- For Image picker start -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: Did you try to append `file:/` to `uri` ? like: `source={{uri:'file://storage/...`

Comment: No not at all. I have removed that instead

Comment: @BlackTiger : Did you find the solution to this problem? If you find it, Please share it. It will be helpful for many people

Comment: No not yet. Have not yet got chance to look at.

Answer (score 30):

Just had this issue, solved it by prepending the filepaths with `file://`

So, instead of:

```
 <Image source={{uri:'/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/myImage.jpg'}} style={myImageStyle} />
```

Use:

```
 <Image source={{uri:'file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/myImage.jpg'}} style={myImageStyle} />
```

Note the 3 consecutive slashes as opposed to just two as suggested by @Cherniv.

Comment: I am using the subject code, but it does not work as needed: <Image source={{ uri: 'file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1861.PNG' }} style={...} />. PLease help to understand what is the problem in my code

Comment: Same than you @David

Answer (score 0):

DSquare is right, unless you're running IOS. In that case 'file://' doesn't work.

```
<Image source={{uri:`${Platform.OS === "android" ? 'file://' : ''}/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/myImage.jpg`}} style={myImageStyle} />
```

The second problem is that this the path `/storage/emulated/0` does not exist on IOS either.

You can make your life easier by using [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs)

```
import RNFS from "react-native-fs";
...
renderPhoto() {
    return <Image source={{uri:`${Platform.OS === "android" ? 'file://' : ''}/${RNFS.PicturesDirectoryPath}/myImage.jpg`}} style={myImageStyle} />
}
```

`RNFS.PicturesDirectoryPath` translates to `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures` on Android.

No more headaches, no more wondering what path is which on which device/platform.

Answer (score 0):

We should get `'READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'` Permission

[refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65265247/13088392)