# Display an image stored on phone

Tags: react-native

I have succesfully been able to take a photo inside my app and store it on the phone, but how do I display it?

I tried this static approach but it does not work (Yes the image is there :) )

```
 <Image width={40} height={40} source={{uri: '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/IMG_20161201_125218.jpg'}} />
```

Comment: Are you using a library to take the picture? you should be able to get the data returned from that. Otherwise, what about the [Camera Roll](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html) API?

Comment: The library im using just returns the path to the file.

Comment: What library is it?

Comment: react-native-camera

Comment: what captureTarget are you using? it might help to post your configuration. https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera#capturetarget

Comment: Omg I cant understand how I've missed captureTarget...I was apparently using `Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.cameraRoll` since I didn't specify it. But my guess is using `Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.temp` will give me the image back.

Docs states that `Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.memory` would have given me the  base64-encoded string back but that one is deprecated

Comment: @D3athSpankcould you find a solution?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Even I faced this issues and got it resolved. You have to prepend the the file path with file:// (mind the double /).

```
<Image source={{uri:'file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/IMG_20161201_125218.jpg'}}
    style={myImageStyle}/>
```

Here's a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878809/react-native-image-not-loading-image-from-sdcard-in-android)!

I hope this helps :)

Comment: It doesn't work for me
file:///storage/emulated/0/appiwell/image/qkpOyUaRla.jpg

Comment: It does not help me

Comment: @TuanNguyen could you find a solution? adding `file://` works only on simulator, on real device it does not work

Comment: @Which device for you? Simply, pick uri of file and add file:// if OS is android. Dont add for ios.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <Image source = {{uri: "file:///storage/emulated/0/appiwell/image/qkpOyUaRla.jpg", 
                    width: responsiveWidth(100), 
                    height: responsiveHeight(100)}}/>
```

Notice, should set width, height inside {uri, width, height}. Width, height in style maybe didn't work.

responsiveWidth, responsiveHeight here 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-dimensions

Answer (score 1):

---

### We should get 'READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' Permission

---

- #### Import

```js
// import 
import { PermissionsAndroid } from "react-native";
```

- #### Function to request permission

```js
// function to request permission
requestStoragePermission = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        {
          title: "Permission title",
          message:
            "Permission message",
          buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
          buttonNegative: "Cancel",
          buttonPositive: "OK",
        }
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log("You can use the EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
      } else {
        console.log("EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission denied");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  };
```

- #### Call the above Function

```js
<Button title="request permissions" onPress={this.requestStoragePermission} />
```

---

### Click this for [reactnative android permissions docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid)